# Use Page content in Blueprint

Tags: php, grav

I try to get data of a page into a blueprint in the admin plugin — using the `themename.php` script in my theme folder.

**people.md** — the content of the page I need

```
---
title: Test Page
people:
  - Holger
  - Peter
  - Simon
---
```

**person.yaml** — the yaml file where I want to use the data from above

```
name:
  type: select
  label: Name
  @data-options: '\Grav\Theme\Themename::names'
```

**person.md** — person.yaml output file

```
---
title: Personal Page
name: Peter
---
```

How can I accomplish that? My idea is to somehow use the grav api and read out the **people.md** — but I dont know how. Is there a simple, dynamic way or is it just a `file_get_contents('path/to/file/people.md')`?